# accessing dictionary-stats in Ansible

Tags: directory, conditional-statements, ansible, stat

I want to take action on a folder, if its empty. So I try to use conditionals on folders-stats. The folders are created with a dictionary.

```
- name: Statistics of folder
  stat: path=/srv/svn/{{ ansible_fqdn }}/{{ item.value.reponame }}
  with_dict: "{{ repos }}"
  register: result

- name: Create repository, if not already
  command:  svnadmin create /srv/svn/{{ ansible_fqdn }}/{{ item.value.reponame }}
  with_dict: "{{ repos }}"
  when: result.stat.size == "6"
#  ignore_errors: True 

- debug: var=repos
```

If I look at the debug-output I can use "size" for my condition. But when running, I get the following error:

```
'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'
```

Maybe it has to do with the "list" of 3 directories? Im running out of ideas.

My workaround is to use no condition and ignore_errors, because on second run, it is already an repository.

Comment: This is because result will be a list, every time you loop through your dict you create a new `result[n]`. Also, I'm not sure a check on `result.stat.size == 6` would be that reliable..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
result.results[0].stat.size
result.results[1].stat.size
result.results[2].stat.size
...
result.results[n].stat.size
```

Comment: But I cant tell at the beginning, how many items there are ... and this doesnt matter - I want to do it for every item.